# How do I add only selected entities from DB to DBContext?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Running the following command will generate all entities of the mapped SQL server database.

```
    Scaffold-DbContext "Server=xxx-xxxx;Database=Northwind;Trusted_Connection=True;user id=sa;password=xxxxx;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

But assume the database has about 80+ tables and I don't want it to create 80+ entities and I only need to create 15 selected entities. Is there a way to achieve this?

Also assume I would want to add / delete selected entities from `DBContext`, is there a command to do this or I have to do it by manually deleting it from `DBContext`?

I use EFCore.

Comment: If you need to add a lot of tables use EF Core Power Tools to pick them through a GUI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the -Tables parameter to specify the tables to include, or you can use EF Core Power Tools.

Comment: EF Core power tools impresses... it seems like it has a good comments on it website.... i believe Power tools sounds more productive than the -Table parameter